# Did Google just get rid of search history?

Tags: google-search

Google Instant is making me a little sick to my stomach. Does anybody know if they're logging all your "potential" searches?  And whether or not your old search history still exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search History is still there. Here's an example with Google Instant:

```
8:54pm Searched for google instant messenger    
8:53pm Searched for test
8:51pm Searched for instant google voice invite 
8:51pm Viewed results for instant messenger (paused for at least 3 seconds with no click)
8:51pm Viewed results for test tube (paused for at least 3 seconds with no click)
8:51pm Searched for test
```

It's not very accurate. I only typed "Google Instant" and it showed results for "google instant messenger" and logged this wrong query.

Answer (score 1):

If you pause on a results page for 3+ seconds it counts as an impression and adds it to your history.  Or if you hit enter to confirm your search.  Or if you click on a result or advert.

Same goes for advert impressions in AdWords.